# adding a border and border radius to an svg element in D3 Maps

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

```
function buildMap(target, data, path, type) {
    var svg = d3.select(target);
    svg
      .selectAll('path')
      .data(data).enter()
      .append('g').attr('class', function(d) {
        var name = sanitize(d.properties.name);
      //  if(name != 'territories'){
          return name + '-group';
      //  }
      })
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', path)
      .attr("style", function() {
        if(this.parentNode.parentNode.className.animVal == 'territories-group' && type == 'full'){
          //console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode.className.animVal == 'territories-group');
          return "outline: thick solid #FFFFFF;";
          }
      })
      .attr('class', function(d) {
        if (d.properties.hasOwnProperty('selected') && d.properties.selected) {
          return 'highlighted';
        }
      })
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        if (type == 'none') {
          return '';
        }
        var transform = getTransform(d, type);
        return transform;
      });
  }
```

I am building a map of the U.S. and U.S. territories. I need to create a circular border around each U.S. territory, however I have had no luck. It can be around the path or `<g>` tag. Right now, I just have an outline which outlines the path and is rectangular. I have also tried changing the outline to a circular shape but I haven't found the correct way, either. I've tried appending a new rectangle, circle, etc but the x and y coordinates are all the same. I cannot find a way to make them dynamic or relative to the child element.

current tree of map

```
  <svg>
   <a>
     <g> 
       <path>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know d3, but setting the stroke and stroke-width properties of the path should add a border to it.  So where you have the

```
.attr("style", function() {
  if(this.parentNode.parentNode.className.animVal == 'territories-group' && type == 'full'){
    return "outline: thick solid #FFFFFF;";
  }
})
```

block, try something like this:

```
.attr('stroke','#FFFFFF')
.attr('stroke-width', 3)
.attr('fill','none')
```

So the whole function would look like this:

```
function buildMap(target, data, path, type) {

    var svg = d3.select(target);

    svg
      .selectAll('path')
      .data(data).enter()
      .append('g').attr('class', function(d) {
        var name = sanitize(d.properties.name);
        //  if(name != 'territories'){
          return name + '-group';
        //  }
      })
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', path)
      .attr('stroke','#FFFFFF')
      .attr('stroke-width', 3)
      .attr('fill','none')
      .attr('class', function(d) {
        if (d.properties.hasOwnProperty('selected') && d.properties.selected) {
          return 'highlighted';
        }
      })
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        if (type == 'none') {
          return '';
        }
        var transform = getTransform(d, type);
        return transform;
      });

}
```

Let me know if that helps you.